# use function in the row of the table to create with *ngFor in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have an array of Object, and I want to create in html page a table where to contain the informations of array. I want use a function (in this moment i am using a simple function that show some information) in the cell of the table. But the information are duplicate and this is a problem. I need to search a solution for this problem

Code Html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="allinfopark">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Città</th>
          <th>indirizzo</th>
          <th>Posti Totali</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let zona of zones;let i=index">
        <tr>
          <td>{{zona.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{info(zona)}}</td>
          <td>{{zona.indirizzo}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code Component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-allinfopark',
  templateUrl: './allinfopark.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./allinfopark.component.css']
})
export class AllinfoparkComponent implements OnInit {

  idgestore:number;
  zones:Array<Zona>;

  constructor(private _activatedroute:ActivatedRoute,private _zonaservice:ZonaService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.idgestore=this._activatedroute.snapshot.params['gestoreId'];
    this.getInfo(this.idgestore);
  }

  getInfo(idgestore:number){
    let zonaObs=this._zonaservice.getInfoParks(idgestore);
    zonaObs.subscribe(data=>{
      this.zones=data;
      console.log(this.zones);
    });

  }



  info(a:any){
    console.log(a);
  }


}
```

This is a screen for the result: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4HYy.jpg)

Comment: "But the information are duplicate" Can you please be a bit more specific what that means? Calling functions in bindings is usually a bad idea. Such functions are called every time Angular runs change detection, which can be quite frequently. Rather store the values in a field (array) and bind to that fields instead.

Comment: I have updated my post add the image where to show the result. Excuse me, there is the way to resolve my problem or i have to invent a other solution? thanks for the your answer

Comment: I don't know what I should look like in the screenshot.

Comment: So, in the component there is the function info that i call in the html page. When I go to page hmtl, the console prints the info that i want to print. Since in the array there is  a 3 objects, i don't understand because the info that i want to print with the console.log they are duplicate... i hope that it is clear my thought

Comment: I explained that already in my first comment. Every time Angular runs change detection, the function will be called.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you very much